# UnicodeDecodeError reading a CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, parsing, python-unicode

I use the following code to read a CSV file:

```
address=r'C:\Users\ssadangi\Desktop\Lynda Python data analytics\Ch02\02_05\Superstore-Sales.csv'
df=pd.read_csv(address,index_col='Order Date',parse_dates=True)
```

The code gives me this error:

> ```
> UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens()
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype()
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._string_convert()
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers._string_box_utf8()
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position 16: invalid start byte
> ```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> ```
> UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-28-3fa20db347ab> in <module>()
> ----> 1 df=pd.read_csv('Superstore-Sales.csv',index_col='Order Date',parse_dates=True)
> ~\Documents\Softwares\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, skip_footer, doublequote, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, memory_map, float_precision)
>     707                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
>     708 
> --> 709         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>     710 
>     711     parser_f.__name__ = name
> ~\Documents\Softwares\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>     453 
>     454     try:
> --> 455         data = parser.read(nrows)
>     456     finally:
>     457         parser.close()
> ~\Documents\Softwares\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
>    1067                 raise ValueError('skipfooter not supported for iteration')
>    1068 
> -> 1069         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
>    1070 
>    1071         if self.options.get('as_recarray'):
> ~\Documents\Softwares\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
>    1837     def read(self, nrows=None):
>    1838         try:
> -> 1839             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
>    1840         except StopIteration:
>    1841             if self._first_chunk:
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_column_data()
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens()
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype()
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._string_convert()
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers._string_box_utf8()
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position 16: invalid start byte
> ```

Comment: Without the original data, there is not much people can tell you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have edited your question for readability using formatting codes (please see [the editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting). I've also tried to make the title more friendly, and added the [python] tag -- you should always use the base language tag.

Comment: Consider editing your question and adding the portion of the CSV file that causes the error -- try removing parts of the CSV file to make it as short as possible but still causes the error, then show us that.

Comment: Tre setting an encoding Ex: `encoding='latin1'` or `encoding='iso-8859-1' `

Comment: Thanks for editing the question @Cris Luengo. This was my first in Stack Overflow. I tried using the formatting codes, but didn't seem to work (even tagging doesn't seem to work). Some issue with the network or browser.

Solved by setting `encoding='ansi'`. Thanks @Rakesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is encoding error when you use pd.read_csv() function you have to define encoding as well

```
address=r'C:\Users\ssadangi\Desktop\Lynda Python data analytics\Ch02\02_05\Superstore-Sales.csv'
df=pd.read_csv(address,index_col='Order Date',parse_dates=True,encoding='latin1') #here i am using encoding attribute
```